# Passing variables from shell script to BTEQ File

Tags: linux, shell, sh, teradata, ksh

I have a shell script(.ksh) inside which I call the BTEQ file to execute SQL query. However, the date of executing the BTEQ file depends on the data availability which another SQL query inside the shell script checks.

**What I want:** I want to pass 'Date' variable from shell script into the BTEQ file so that the query that executes takes that 'date' into account.

Shell Script and the variable inside the check_data.ksh

```
Rundate=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
cat ~/.tdlogon_simba sample_TD.btq | bteq >> ${log_file} 2>&1
```

Bteq file code (Sample_TD.btq)

```
sel * from test_table
where cond = Rundate
```

In the above code, I want 'Rundate' to come from check_data.ksh

**What I don't want**: In reality, my query is very big around 3000 line of code so I don't want to execute the query inside the shell script.

***EDITED***

**What I want:** I want to have a variable RUNDATE (containing DATE value) and want to use that variable in every place. The value of RUNDATE should be assigned at the starting of the shell script, basically, it should be read only once and should remain same throughout the batch process i.e. it should not change even a new day has come if the process is running.

I can read the +1 day in shell script using

```
RUNDATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "+1 day"`
```

Now I'm running two batch processes run_data_check and run_batch inside the shell script in which I'll be passing this date to the BTQ file. Data_check is an iterative process and I don't know when the data is coming. Thus, I want the date to be fixed to check for that data for that day.

If I use

```
run_tdcheck
sed "s/RUNDATE/$(date +'%Y-%m-%d' -d '+1 day')/g" ~/.tdlogon_simba test.btq | bteq >> ${log_file} 2>&1
```

Then it doesn't help my cause since everytime this function runs it consider the system date and modifies accordingly. I want that RUNDATE to be fixed till the batch processing is complete.

Any way by which I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply update your script to change the keyword `Rundate` in your `.btq` file using `sed` :

```
rundate="$(date -d '+1 day' +%Y-%m-%d)"
sed "s/Rundate/$rundate/g" ~/.tdlogon_simba sample_TD.btq | bteq >> ${log_file} 2>&1
```

The `sed` command will change all occurrences of the keyword `Rundate`. You might want to refine this by having a more restrictive search for example:

```
sed "s/cond = Rundate/cond = $rundate/g"
```

Comment: Thanks, @oliv. It seems to work fine with this. 
Was just wondering as to how this will work when I have to send multiple arguments together in the Bteq file like Rundate, Var1,Var2 like parameters/ values. Can you help me with that.

Comment: You need to extend the `sed` command, with for example `s/var1/$var1/g`. Add as many as you want separated by a semi colon `;`. The `var1` is the keyword in your query, the `$var1` is the bash variable holding the value.

Comment: I realized that the solution you gave was not really fulfilling the condition. Maybe I didn't provide the right use-case. I have edited my question. Can you help me solve that issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are really looking for a here document.

```
bteq <<____HERE >>"$log_file" 2>&1
    sel \* from test_table
    where cond = $(date +"%F");
____HERE
```

This avoids the pesky external file, and also coincidentally removes the fugly [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)

If you want the date to stay put once you have calculated it (so that it doesn't change underneath if the script runs past midnight),

```
rundate=$(date +%F -d '+1 day')
bteq <<____HERE >>"$log_file" 2>&1
    sel \* from test_table
    where cond = $rundate;
____HERE
```

Any variable or wildcard in the here document will be evaluated by the shell before `bteq` runs (as long as you don't quote the here-document delimiter); that's why the asterisk has to be backslash-escaped (otherwise the shell would expand the glob to a list of all the files in the current directory).

By the by, you should avoid uppercase for you own variables, as uppercase is reserved for system use.

The same could be done with `sed`, of course -- just make sure you don't use single quotes, as those prevent the shell from seeing and modifying the variable.

```
sed "s/RUNDATE/$rundate/g" ~/.tdlogon_simba test.btq |
bteq >> ${log_file} 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks, @tripleee. I have edited my question to state my use-case more clearly. Can you advise me now as to how should I proceed.